# Trying to set the path in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, xcopy

I am trying to copy some pictures from one folder and move it to another folder using batch. I am having trouble in setting the path since the path contains spaces in it.If I remove the spaces from folder it works fine but with spaces it gives error that **cannot find the path**.. here is the code.

```
@echo off 

SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set backupcmd=echo
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y

set "filesw=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Numerical Analysis\*.png"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b %filesw%') do (
  if "%%~xi"==".pdf" set "dest=D"
  if "%%~xi"==".docx" set "dest=P"
  if "%%~xi"==".zip" set "dest=Z"
  if "%%~xi"==".rar" set "dest=Z"
  if "%%~di"=="C:" if "!dest!"=="Z" set "dest=!dest!3"
  %backupcmd% "%%i" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Barat\MOVIE!dest!\"
)

@echo off 
cls
```

It would be really helpful if you guys help me fix this path problem.

Comment: Change `dir /s /b %filesw%` to `dir /s /b "%filesw%"`; state `%backupcmd% "%%~fi"`; check if `%drive%` is set...

Comment: @aschipfl I tried to change the dir path but still nothing.

Comment: what is odrive? Did you want to say : "%odrive%\Personal\PICS..." in your command arguments?

Comment: Your dir command is looking for .PNG files which will never match any of your IF statements.  Personally I would use the FOR /R command instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem, specifically "setting the path since the path contains spaces in it" leading to "cannot find the path" is to "quote the filespec" Thus:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b "%filesw%"') do (
```

In this way, the string between the double-quotes is used literally (although certain special characters with a meaning to batch like `&^)!` need to be escaped; that is, preceded by a caret `^`). As you have it, the `dir` command will be executed with multiple arguments since spaces are separators and the variable `filesw` will be substituted literally into the `dir` command before execution - and like most commands, `dir` uses spaces (commas, tabs, semicolons) as separators.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. Use the FOR /R command to walk the directory tree looking for the file type you want.  But I am just guessing at what you are trying to do.

```
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y

set "filep=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Numerical Analysis"

for /R "%filep%" %%i in (.) do (
    if "%%~xi"==".pdf" set "dest=D"
    if "%%~xi"==".docx" set "dest=P"
    if "%%~xi"==".zip" set "dest=Z"
    if "%%~xi"==".rar" set "dest=Z"
    if "%%~di"=="C:" if "!dest!"=="Z" set "dest=!dest!3"
    %backupcmd% "%%i" "%drive%\Personal\PICS\Wedding\Barat\MOVIE!dest!\"
)
```